# Storing parsed value and attribute to arraylist

Tags: java, sax, saxparser

following program parse an xml file properly and diplaying its name element value and rel's link attribute value.
I want to store these two value in ArrayList      <UserDetail>

UserDetail class:

```
public class UserDetail {

private String name;
private String mailid;

public String getMailid() {
    return mailid;
}

public void setMailid(String mailid) {
    this.mailid = mailid;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

SAX Parsing Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
 import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
 import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
 import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
 import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
 import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class ReadXMLFile {



public static void main(String argv[]) {


    try {

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

        DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

            boolean name = false;
            boolean link = false;


            public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                    Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

                //System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);

                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("fullName")) {
                    name = true;
                }
                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                    System.out.println("\t" + attributes.getValue("rel"));
                }
            }

            public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                    String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("fullName")) {

                    name = false;
                }
                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                    link = false;
                }
            }

            public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

                if (name) {
                    System.out.println("First Name : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                    name = false;
                }

            }
          };

        saxParser.parse("D://abc.xml", handler);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

XML document:

```
 <feed>
   <entry>
     <fullName>Manish Sahu</fullName>
     <link rel='abc'/>
     <link rel='self'/>
     <link rel='edit'/>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Comment: You want to save two strings into an ArrayList<UserDetail> variable?

Answer (score 1):

Keep a reference to the current User object being build.

For element "entry" instantiate a new UserDetails at startElement, and store it into the list at endElement (you could add validation here if you want). Then set the current user to null in order to avoid accidental modification (e.g. a link element outside of entry).

For element "link" add the value of the "ref" attribute to the user details (there should be an addLink method, or similar, in UserDetails instead of an scalar setter).

For element "fullName", concatenate the character data into a StringBuilder (since characters may be called more than once, depending on the parser implementation) and set the name of the "current user" at endElement, then clearing the SB.

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {

//must be final since it is referenced from an anonymous class
final List<UserDetail> users = new ArrayList <UserDetail>(); 

try {

    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

    DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

        String element;
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        UserDetails user=null;

        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
             this.element=qName;

             //create a new user
             if (element.equals("entry")) user = new UserDetails();

             //save attribute <link rel="...">
             if (element.equals("link")&&user!=null) 
                 user.addLink(attributes.getValue("rel"));
        }

        public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
           if (element.equals("fullName")) {
                  //store the name given in character data
                  user.setName(sb.toString());
                  sb.setLength(0);
           } else if (element.equals("entry")) {                                    
              users.add(user); //store the current user
              user=null;                   
           }               
        }

        public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException            {
            if (element.equals("fullName")) sb.append(ch, start, length);
        }
      };

    saxParser.parse("D://abc.xml", handler);

    //do something with the users
    for (UserDetails user;users) System.out.println(user.getName()+" "+user.getMailid());

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   //catching Exception is not a good practice!
}
```

}

I haven't compiled the code above, but it is something similar to what I use to do when parsing XML. Saving the qName instead of setting a flag helps when you are dealing with a more complex content model. (In some case, I use to mantain a Stack, pushing the element name on startElement and poping it on endElement).